# Highlighting matched results on _all fields

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I want the matched results to be highlighted. This works for me if I mention the field name and it returns the highlighted text, however if I give the field as "_all", it is not returning any value.
This works for me:

```
        curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_search?q=stackoverflow&size=999" -d '{
        "highlight":{
                    "fields":{
                             "my_field":{}
                    }
        }
}'
```

This returns the expected value as follows: 
[highlight] => stdClass Object ( [my_field] => Array ( [0] => *stackoverflow* is the best website for techies ) )

But when I give this:

```
        curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_search?q=stackoverflow&size=999" -d '{
        "highlight":{
                    "fields":{
                             "_all":{}
                    }
        }
}'
```

I get null value/no result.

```
[highlight] => stdClass Object ( [_all] => Array () )
```

How do I get it to work on any field so that I don't have to mention the field name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to map the _all field as stored. The mapping below should do the trick. Note though that this will add to the index size.

```
{
  "my_type": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": true,
        "store": "yes"
      }
  }}
```

Comment: Is this a one time only operation, for each type? If so, what uri is this invoked on, `/my_index/my_type`?

Comment: Be aware the ES [does not recommend storing the _all field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/mapping-all-field.html):

"Although it is possible to store the _all field, it is basically an aggregation of all fields, which means more data will be stored, and highlighting it might produce strange results."

Answer (score 28):

### To avoid the need to add `_all` as a stored field in your index

An alternative quick fix: use `*` instead of `_all`:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_search?q=stackoverflow&size=999" -d '{
  "highlight":{
    "fields":{
      "*":{}
    }
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 16):

If you are using `ES 2.x` then you need to set `require_field_match` option to `false` due to [changes made](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_search_changes.html#_only_highlight_queried_fields), From the doc

> The default value for the require_field_match option has changed from false to true, meaning that the highlighters will, by default, only take the fields that were queried into account.
>
> This means that, when querying the _all field, trying to highlight on
>   any field other than _all will produce no highlighted snippets.

```
"highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    },
    "require_field_match": false
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

This library has functions for query highlighting including highlighting across all fields. The README explains how to create an elasticsearch index with _all field stored etc:
https://github.com/niranjan-uma-shankar/Elasticsearch-PHP-class