# ElasticSearch Highlighting Not highlighting

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having difficulty understanding how to get highlighting to work.
My queries are returning the item, but I do not see the tags that would cause the highlight.

Here's the set up for the test index:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/testfoo' -d '{
    "mappings": {
        "entry": {
            "properties": {
                "id": { "type": "integer" },
                "owner": { "type": "string" },
                "target": {
                    "properties": {
                        "id": { "type": "integer" },
                        "type": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index": "not_analyzed"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "body": { "type": "string" },
                "body_plain": { "type": "string"}
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Here's a couple of inserted documents:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/testfoo/entry/1' -d'{
    "id": 1,
    "owner": "me",
    "target": {
        "type": "event",
        "id":   100
    },
    "body": "<div>Message One has foobar in it</div>",
    "body_plain": "Message One has foobar in it"
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/testfoo/entry/2' -d'{
    "id": 2,
    "owner": "me",
    "target": {
        "type": "event",
        "id":   200
    },
    "body": "<div>Message One has no bar in it</div>",
    "body_plain": "Message One has no bar in it"
}'
```

A Simple search returns the expected document:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/testfoo/_search?pretty' -d '{
    "query": {
        "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "foobar"
        }
    }
}'
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.09492774,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "testfoo",
      "_type" : "entry",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : 0.09492774,
      "_source" : {
        "id" : 1,
        "owner" : "me",
        "target" : {
          "type" : "event",
          "id" : 100
        },
        "body" : "<div>Message One has foobar in it</div>",
        "body_plain" : "Message One has foobar in it"
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

However, when I add "highlighting" I get the same JSON but body_plain is not "highlighted" with the matching term:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/testfoo/_search?pretty' -d '{
    "query":{
            "query": {
                "simple_query_string":{
                    "query":"foobar"
                }
            }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "pre_tags": [ "<div class=\"highlight\">" ],
        "post_tags": [ "</div>" ],
        "fields": {
            "_all": {
                "fragment_size": 10,
                "number_of_fragments": 1
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        "_score"
    ],
    "_source": [ "target", "id", "body_plain", "body" ],
    "min_score": 0.9,
    "size":10
}'
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "testfoo",
      "_type" : "entry",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "id" : 1,
        "body" : "<div>Message One has foobar in it</div>",
        "target" : {
          "id" : 100,
          "type" : "event"
        },
        "body_plain" : "Message One has foobar in it"
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Where I was expecting body_plain to look like

```
  Message One has <div class="highlight">foobar</div> in it
```

Wondering what I'm doing wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: check the [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286404/highlighting-matched-results-on-all-fields)  here should be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html)

> In order to perform highlighting, the actual content of the field is
>   required. If the field in question is stored (has store set to true in
>   the mapping) it will be used, otherwise, the actual _source will be
>   loaded and the relevant field will be extracted from it.
>
> The _all field cannot be extracted from _source, so it can only be
>   used for highlighting if it mapped to have store set to true.

You have two ways to solve this. Either you change your mapping to store the `_all` field:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "entry": {
      "_all": {              <-- add this
        "store": true
      },
      "properties": {
        ...
```

Or you change your query to this:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/testfoo/_search?pretty' -d '{
    "query":{
            "query": {
                "simple_query_string":{
                    "query":"foobar"
                }
            }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "pre_tags": [ "<div class=\"highlight\">" ],
        "post_tags": [ "</div>" ],
        "require_field_match": false,             <-- add this
        "fields": {
            "*": {                                <-- use this                  
                "fragment_size": 10,
                "number_of_fragments": 1
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        "_score"
    ],
    "_source": [ "target", "id", "body_plain", "body" ],
    "min_score": 0.9,
    "size":10
}'
```

Comment: Thanks Val, that did the trick.  I obviously did not make the connection when reading that.