# ElasticSearch: Highlighting with Stemming

Tags: elasticsearch

I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39258928/elasticsearch-highlighting-not-highlighting) and attempted to understand the documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html), but this is complicated.

**The problem (I think):**

**[update 1]**

I am using Scala for my code and interface with ES High Level Java API.

I have a stemming analyzer configured. If I search for `responsibilities` i get results for `responsibilities` and `responsibility`. That's great.

**BUT**

Only the documents with the term `responsibilities` return highlights.
This is because the search is on the stemmed content , i.e., `responsib`. However, the highlight is against the unstemmed content. Hence, it finds `responsibilities` which was a search criteria, but not `responsibility`, which wasn't.

If I set the highlighter to highlight on the stemmed content, it returns nothing at all. I guess because it is comparing `resonsib` with `responsibilities`

**Search**

I an using the Java high level API. The problem is not the code itself.
Currently, I am highlighting only the `content` field, returning only `responsibilities`. Highlighting `content.english` seems to return nothing

```
 private def buildHighlighter(): HighlightBuilder = {
    import org.elasticsearch.search.fetch.subphase.highlight.HighlightBuilder
    val highlightBuilder = new HighlightBuilder
    val highlightContent = new HighlightBuilder.Field("content")
    highlightContent.highlighterType("unified")
    highlightBuilder.field(highlightContent)
    highlightBuilder

  }
```

**Mapping (adumbrated)**

```html
{
 "settings": {
  "number_of_shards": 3,
  "analysis": {
   "filter": {
    "english_stop": {
     "type": "stop",
     "stopwords": "_english_"
    },
    "english_keywords": {
     "type": "keyword_marker",
     "keywords": []
    },
    "english_stemmer": {
     "type": "stemmer",
     "language": "english"
    },
    "english_possessive_stemmer": {
     "type": "stemmer",
     "language": "possessive_english"
    }
   },
   "analyzer": {
    "english": {
     "tokenizer": "standard",
     "filter": [
      "english_possessive_stemmer",
      "lowercase",
      "english_stop",
      "english_keywords",
      "english_stemmer"
     ]
    }
   }
  }
 },
 "mappings": {
  "_doc": {
   "properties": {
    "title": {
     "type": "text",
          "fields": {
           "english": {
             "type":     "text",
              "analyzer": "english"
            }
          }
    },
    "content": {
          "type": "text",
           "fields": {
            "english": {
              "type":     "text",
               "analyzer": "english"
             }
          }
   
   }
  }
 }
}
```

**[update 2]**

Scala code to implement search:

```
def searchByField(indices: Seq[ESIndexName], terms: Seq[(String, String)], size: Int = 20): SearchResponse = {

    val searchRequest = new SearchRequest
    searchRequest.indices(indices.map(idx => idx.completeIndexName()): _*)
    searchRequest.source(buildTargetFieldsMatchQuery(terms, size))

    searchRequest.indicesOptions(IndicesOptions.strictSingleIndexNoExpandForbidClosed())

    client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT)
  }
```

and query is built as follows:

```
private def buildTargetFieldsMatchQuery(termsByField: Seq[(String, String)], size: Int): SearchSourceBuilder = {

    val query = new BoolQueryBuilder

    termsByField.foreach {
      case (field, term) =>

        if (field == "content") {
          logger.debug(field + " should have " + term)
          query.should(new MatchQueryBuilder(field+standardAnalyzer, term.toLowerCase))
          query.should(new MatchQueryBuilder(field, term.toLowerCase))
        }
        else if (field == "title"){
          logger.debug(field + " should have " + term)
          query.should(new MatchQueryBuilder(field+standardAnalyzer, term.toLowerCase())).boost
        }
        else {
          logger.debug(field + " should have " + term)
        query.should(new MatchQueryBuilder(field, term.toLowerCase))
      }

    }
    val sourceBuilder: SearchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder()
    sourceBuilder.query(query)
    sourceBuilder.from(0)
    sourceBuilder.size(size)
    sourceBuilder.timeout(new TimeValue(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    sourceBuilder.highlighter(buildHighlighter())

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

With plain REST the following is working fine for me:

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "english_stop": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": "_english_"
        },
        "english_keywords": {
          "type": "keyword_marker",
          "keywords": []
        },
        "english_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "english"
        },
        "english_possessive_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "possessive_english"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "english": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "english_possessive_stemmer",
            "lowercase",
            "english_stop",
            "english_keywords",
            "english_stemmer"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "content": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "english": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "english"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/_doc/
{
  "content": "This is my responsibility"
}

POST test/_doc/
{
  "content": "These are my responsibilities"
}

GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "content.english": "responsibilities"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "content.english": {
        "type": "unified"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result is then:

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "test",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "5D5PPGoBqgTTLzdtM-_Y",
    "_score" : 0.18232156,
    "_source" : {
      "content" : "This is my responsibility"
    },
    "highlight" : {
      "content.english" : [
        "This is my <em>responsibility</em>"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "test",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "5T5PPGoBqgTTLzdtZe8U",
    "_score" : 0.18232156,
    "_source" : {
      "content" : "These are my responsibilities"
    },
    "highlight" : {
      "content.english" : [
        "These are my <em>responsibilities</em>"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Looking at your Java / Groovy (?) code it looks close enough to the [example in the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-search.html#java-rest-high-search-request-highlighting). Could you log the actual query you are running, so we can figure out what is going wrong? Generally it should work like this.

Comment: You have already been very helpful. At least I know now that I am probably looking in the wrong place. I have made substantial updates to the original question. Again, I thank you

Comment: That will be kind of hard to reproduce. Can you just log the actual query you are running? That might be easier to debug.

Comment: good idea! (I'm new-ish to ES). I am swamped atm, but will try to get to this in a day or two. Thanks for your time and attention